# MySQL server has gone away when running query from mysql client on mongosqld

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I installed mongodb on ubuntu server using docker. 
I installed mongo BI connector on the server.
I also installed the DSN following the [instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/tutorial/create-system-dsn) and I can use the `iusql` to connect and run sql query.
However, I'm facing an issue when I use the mysql client to connect the mongo BI connector.
When I use the mysql client, I can list the databases, but `ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away` comes out when I running any other query.
Is anyone there has faced this issue plz help me?
btw, i'm trying to use mongo bi connector as database for metabase.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happen when I using the mysql-client 5.7.31 
Using mysql-client 5.7.30 solves the problem.